# Using CSS to detect if child exists

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following menu and when I use the below CSS I have a small arrow appear under it, but I'd only like the arrow to appear **if** the `li` has a `.subnav` present

**CSS**

```
.nav li: hover {
    background: url(.. / img / template / nav - hover.png) no - repeat bottom center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>

            <div class="subnav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">menu item</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu item</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/companies">Companies</a>

            <div class="subnav">
                <ul class="companylist1">
                    <li><a href="#">1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/locations">Locations</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/news">News</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @M1K1O: But selectors are entirely based on conditions/predicates. That has nothing to do with CSS not being a programming language. And please don't use ` for formatting emphasis.

Comment: if you want to use just css then apply the background to the div instead of li. `.nav li > div.subnav:hover`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can achieve this as of now is by using `nth-of-type`

```
.nav > ul > li:nth-of-type(1) > a, .nav > ul > li:nth-of-type(2) > a {
    color: #f00;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/94JCJ/)

In the above selector, am selecting `a` which is directly nested under 1st and 2nd `li` which are further nested to `ul` which is further nested in `.nav`

Comment: Have used this sort of method but used the following code `.nav > ul > li:nth-of-type(1):hover, .nav > ul > li:nth-of-type(2):hover`

Comment: @Beardy yea, you can use `:hover` if you want the effect on hover :)

Comment: @Beardy, you said "only like the arrow to appear if the li has a .subnav present" and this won't satisfy that...

Answer (score 1):

If div.subnav will have absolute position, just put it before the anchor:

```
<li>
    <div class="subnav">
        <ul class="companylist1">
            <li>
                <a href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="/companies">Companies</a>
</li>
```

and then:

```
div.subnav + a {...}
```

or:

```
div.subnav + a:hover {...}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/2ZBnY/

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that with pure css is placing arrow inside to the "subnav" container. But you can do this with jquery easily.

```
if ($(".nav li .subnav").length > 0)) {
    // .. set background
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this is not possible with CSS alone. You best bet is to add a class to the two `<li>`s with `.subnav` children.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't create `if`statements in CSS, you either need to add this with javascript/jQuery, or get creative...

I would suggest creating the down arrow with a pseudo-element (or actual HTML element) **within** the `.subnav` item, then positioning it absolutely outside of the .subnav so that it appears to be within the parent li item.

By doing this, the arrow will only be shown if the subnav is present. You would have to play with how you are showing/hiding the .subnav, however, because settings `display:none;` would obviously also cause the arrow to not appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create conditions in CSS however, you might be able to work it differently.

How about showing the image on the `.subnav` class instead? Put it at the top center instead of the bottom center of the `li`.

The selector would be something like `.nav li > .subnav:hover` for the image.

Comment: The `.subnav` is full width of the page, whereas the `.nav` is only a certain width. That is why the `background-image` action is on the `.nav li:hover` at the moment, I just hoped there was a way of detecting if `.subnav` existed inside the `li`

Comment: @Beardy My [**solutionn**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18483065/1577396) seems to work. but not sure why someone downvoted it.